# difference between create-route and map-route in cloud foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am struggling to see what the difference is between `cf create-route` and `cf map-route` or when I would use one and not the other.

My requirement is to create a cloudfront distribution in aws that would forward requests to cloud foundry.

I have a custom domain my-custom-domain.com:

which I add to cf with:

```
cf create-domain MY_ORG my-custom-domain.com
```

do I use:

```
create-route my-space my-custom-domain.com --hostname myapp            # my-custom-domain.com
```

or do I use:

```
cf map-route my-app my-custom-domain.com --hostname myhost            # my-custom-domain.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written [here](https://cli.cloudfoundry.org/en-US/cf/create-route.html) `create-route` - Create a url route in a space for later use. Not necessary that this route needs to be mapped to an App. It can just be created and can be left as such for later usage

As written [here](https://cli.cloudfoundry.org/en-US/cf/map-route.html) `map-route` - Add a url route to an app. For this a Route should be already created. Suppose if you directly execute a `map-route` command with an `URL` thats not created already, then `map-route` will first create an URL and then map it against the `APP_NAME` that you have mentioned.

`cf-create-domain` is to create a domain for your Org (not a share domain that can be used across all the Orgs). This is mainly done when you are using a Vanity-URL such as `www.dothis.cfapp.com/your_end_point`

So once you create a custom-domain, you will have to follow `create-route` or `map-route` syntax and then map the newly created domain to your App

Comment: How can i add a Vanity URL that looks this "wwwdev.servicename.com"

Comment: to do that, the vanity URL  `servicename.com` should be available in your space and once it is avaibable, you can execute `cf map-route` command to attach wwwdev to the service name and map it